# Is there anyway to bypass discord's suspicious activity screen when joining a server via python?

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, verification, exploit

I am currently writing a script in Python that allows you to join a discord server using the invite code and the authorization token of the account you wish to join with.

Here is the code:

```py
link = f"https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invite/{self.invite}?with_counts=true"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36', 'Authorization': token}

if not self.using_proxies:
    join = requests.post(link, headers=header)
else:
    random_proxy = get_random_proxy()  # Returns random proxy from a list.
    try:
        auth = HTTPProxyDigestAuth(random_proxy[1][0], random_proxy[1][1])  # user/pass
        join = requests.post(link, proxies=random_proxy[0], auth=auth, headers=header)
    except KeyError:  # If there is no random_proxy[1], then do not try to authenticate user/pass
        join = requests.post(link, proxies=random_proxy, headers=header)  # if no user/pass needed
```

This code results in discord's suspicious activity, phone verification screen after just joining one server with one token, with or without proxies.

I am currently wondering if it is indeed possible to bypass being detected, somehow. I've tried other User-Agents and including other headers; did not work. Surely there has to be some method to the madness and, if there is it, I ask if anyone knows.

Thanks!

**Edit(s)**:

I should point out that the code does work as intended, in regards to actually getting the account to join the server.

I should also point out that the code is planned to be for open-source, public use - so using extremely, account specific headers may not work *if* there is no way for the end-user of this supposed program to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Discord, but I'm pretty sure they perform some JavaScript checks to "ensure" they're being accessed to by a browser and not a script like you're trying to do.

I cannot 100% assure this will work, but if I were you I would try using [splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is a browser automation tool. It's based on [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) but provides a better abstraction, making it easier to use. This way, your script will be able to make HTTP requests using an actual browser (and therefore executing JavaScript).

Note however that Discord might somehow also be able to detect that you are using a headless browser so it might not fix your issue.

Comment: Discord is an Electron app and @Catterall is hitting the API so this is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You answered the question yourself. Discord detects suspicious activity based on the fact that phone number verification is not done. I tested it with my own Authorization token on a server owned by another of my accounts and this error was not triggered as on the account where I have verified the phone number.

**Thus the solution is simply to verify your account with an actual phone number.** If you're actually looking for a way to bypass phone verification instead, I would suggest to create a new question on the [Security Stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) asking that.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular belief, you don't need to use a headless browser or phone number to automatically join a server via script. Instead, you need to specify a header in  the HTTP request labeled: "X-Super-Properties". You can think of this value as a second authorization token Discord users for specific endpoints. To get this value, just log into Discord on any browser and copy the header off an API request (just like with your token).